# How can we find $m_2$ such that $m \equiv m_1 m_2 \pmod n$ ?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $m, m_1 \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.

How can we find $m_2$ such that $m \equiv m_1 m_2 \pmod n$ ??

Coud you give me some hints??

Comment: so given that $m \equiv m_1 \pmod{n}$ you want to find $m_2$ ?? is that what u are asking

Comment: Hint: Modular inverse of $m_1$, or Bezout.

Comment: Note that this is not always possible: in $\Bbb Z / 4 \Bbb Z$, if $m = \hat 3$ and $m_1 = \hat 2$, there is no $m_2$ with the required properties.

Comment: @MaryStar: use extended euclidean algorithm to find $m_2,\,x$ in $m_1m_2+nx=d$ where $d=\gcd(n,m_1)$ and then multiply by $m/d$. If $d\nmid m$ there's no solution exist.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ \exists x\!:\ ax \equiv b \pmod n \iff \exists x,y\!:\ ax+ny = b \iff (a,n)\mid b,\ $ by Bezout.

When it holds $\,\color{#c00}{(a,n)c = b},\,$  so scaling $ $ Bezout: $\, aj+nk = \color{#c00}{(a,n)}\ $ by $\,\color{#c00}c\,$ yields a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It does not always exist if $m$ and $m_1$ are arbitrary integers, more precisely, it exists if and only if $g\mid m$, where $g=\gcd(n,m_1)$ (however, this is the case in your problem since by definition $m_1$ is invertible modulo $n$). You can try to prove this by your own using the fact that for every pair of integers $p,q$ there exist integers $x,y$ such that

$$\gcd(p,q)=xp+yq$$

(those integers can be found using **euclidean algorithm** which gives the algorithm you're looking for).

Comment: Oh sure!, I didn't notice that. I'll add some details. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

First notice that it doesn't always have a solution (for example, let $n=6$, $m_1=2$ and $m=1$). It has a solution $iff$ $gcd(n,m_1)|m$.

Supposing that $gcd(n,m_1)|m$, you can always solve this equation.

First consider the case in which $gcd(n,m_1)=1$.

There are several ways to solve that, but one is to find the inverse of $m_1 \ mod\ n$. i.e. to find $m_2^*$ such that $m_1.m_2^*=1 \ mod \ n$.$^+$ Then it's not hard to see that your answer will be the remainder of division of $m_2^*.m$ by $n$.

For the case in which $gcd(n,m_1)=d>1$, you could divide the equation by $d$, and solve something like $m_1'.m_2'=m/d \ (mod \ n/d)$ in which $m_1'=m_1/d$ and $m_2'=m_2/d$, just like above. Then your answers for $m_2$ will be $m_2'$,$m_2'+m/d$,$m_2'+2m/d$,...$m_2'+(d-1)m/d$.

$^+$to solve the equation $ax=1 \ mod \ n$ when $gcd(n,a)=1$, use Euclid algorithm to find s and t such that $ns+at=1$ (Bezout's theorem), then you will have $x=t \ mod \ n$.